# How to add dates to MySQL result on which there are no records in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

Consider the following "messages" table:

```
_date        message
-------------------------
2012-02-22   hello
2012-02-22   another msg!
2012-03-05   foobar
2012-03-22   testing
2012-03-22   goodbye
2012-03-22   test test
```

I want to count the number of messages per day, but also want to include all the days on which there are no messages. Say I want to count all messages between 2012-02-01 and 2012-03-29, then the query result should be:

```
_date        messsages
----------------------
2012-02-01   0
2012-02-02   0
...
2012-02-22   2
2012-02-23   0
...
2012-03-01   0
2012-03-02   0
2012-03-03   0
2012-03-04   0
2012-03-05   1
...
2012-03-22   3
...
2012-03-29   0
```

Is this possible within MySQL?

Comment: If the record has no date, how do you know that date is between 2012-02-01 and 2012-03-29?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it -

```
SELECT date_range.`date`, COUNT(messages._date)
FROM (
    SELECT '2012-02-01' + INTERVAL (id - 1) DAY AS `date`
    FROM dummy
    WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 58
    ORDER BY id ASC
) AS date_range
LEFT JOIN messages
    ON date_range.`date` = messages._date
GROUP BY date_range.`date` ASC
```

For this example dummy is any table with an integer based id field with a contiguous set covering the required date range. In this case you would need ids from 1 to 58.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161749/mysql-aggregating-orders-across-date-range-with-null-values-for-count), you will need to use a stored procedure that will create a temporary table of all the dates in the range and join the messages table to that.  You cannot return records from a table that does not have them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possibly similar solution using the keyword BETWEEN on another answer here. I've not personally used BETWEEN in SQL before, but it looks promising. I'm unsure on whether it will count 0 for days that don't exist in the table, but it may get you started atleast.

They also mention an uglier method of having a "helper" table to use against a JOIN; this would definitely get you the 0 counts, but would be kind of messy in my opinion. If you decide to go that route, I'd suggest trying a temporary table maybe using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/895185/1301139

Comment: a BETWEEN x AND y is just another way of writing (a >= x AND a <=y) - [Comparison Function and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running this query often or if you don't want (or can't) create a new table to left join with, you can generate the data dynamically as steted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552508/dynamically-creating-date-periods-using-mysql).